# Problem packaging a simple Node.js express server into standalone executable in Windows

Tags: node.js

As a test I prepared this simple index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Server running on port " + port + ".");
});
```

Then I try to package this server as a standalone Windows executable:

```
pkg index.js -t node10-win-x64
```

Using command prompt in Windows, I type "index.exe" in the folder with index.exe. 
I do not see the console log at all.

Visiting http://localhost:1337 in browser also failed to see anything.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below command in the command prompt at the location of index.exe file:

```
index.exe index.js
```

Comment: besides I thought i am supposed to hide my javascript files using pkg.

Comment: after running this request have you checked the api from POSTMAN?